# Powershell script to download files from a Google Drive

Tags: powershell, google-api, google-drive-api, powershell-4.0

I need a Powershell script that can download a file from a Google Drive and then delete it. I cannot find any examples of this being done in Powershell though. The piece that I am struggling with is how to connect to the Google Drive API with the service account's credentials.

I have an existing script that works, but the service account that it uses doesn't have the appropriate access, and this can't be changed. This script uses a different method to connect to the Google Drive api, which involves parsing a .json file. However, the new service account I am trying to use does not have a .json file. I have a username and password though, but I'm not sure how to connect to the api this way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.